# Catching an error in react native, but keeping the app functional

Tags: react-native, error-handling

Whenever a fatal error happens in our react native app, the entire app crashes and turns white.  You have to restart the app again.  Is there anyway to catch this error (bad JSON) and show a message, but keep the app functional, like going back to the previous screen or able to click header or tabs?

I understand you can catch errors globally, but can the app stay functional afterwards?

Comment: I'd recommend reading the following: https://react.dev/reference/react/Component#catching-rendering-errors-with-an-error-boundary